# Create repeated service with alarm

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

Im try to create a service in my app to update data everyday at 2pm. I want to set a repeating alarm which triggers a service to fetch the data for me. This has nothing to do with UI thread and should work even when the app is closed.

I can't seem to get my service to start.

Here is my code in my activity where I create the alarm

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20); // HOUR
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // MIN
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // SEC
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, VenueUpdater.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Main.this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Then my service class

```
public class VenueUpdater extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("SERVICE", "onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("SERVICE", "onDestroy");
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    super.onStart(intent, startid);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("SERVICE", "onStart");
}

}
```

and in my Manifest just before I close my application tag

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name="services.VenueUpdater" />

</application>
```

I've checked some other examples and code where I've used services and the code seems to be fine but still doesn't work. Also I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this as the same alarm may end up being created multiple times but there may be a Pending intent Flag I can use to check that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set your alarm to go off at 8PM, not 2PM with this:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20); // HOUR
```

If you want to make sure that your alarm isn't scheduled multiple times, you can cancel any previously scheduled alarms before setting the alarm, like this:

```
alarm.cancel(pintent);
```

Also, this call to the `AlarmManager`:

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Will set your alarm to go off at 8PM and then every 30 seconds after that. Is that what you want?

**EDIT Show how to set the alarm to repeat once per day at 2PM**

To schedule the alarm to repeat once per day at 2PM, use this:

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
```

Comment: No I want it just one everyday at 2pm

Comment: Thanks alot, I set hour of day to 8pm just to test with current time. I'll test with time in next 5 mins and come back to accept answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

1) In `Service` subclass use `onStartCommad` method to start all service routine. Not onStart/onCreate.
2) Here is example of my AndroidManife:

```
<service android:name=".service.AlertService" />
```

3) `PendingIntent` will everlap previous one (i.e. overlap alam) if it uses the same `requestCode` (the second param of `getService` method) and flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is used as last param.

Try it.

Comment: `onStart()` is deprecated, but still works. `onCreate()` is called in the service when it is first created (after the constructor is called).